# Why do Windows AV software detect strings with case-sensitivitely?

Tags: windows, antivirus

As Windows is case-insensitive, the string `mimikatz` can be evaluated the same as `MIMIKATZ` or `MimIkaTZ`. A naive method of AV evasion by switching cases of some characters in suspicious string has been demonstrated [here](https://youtu.be/9pwMCHlNma4?t=2630) where the string `wdigest.dll` is simply replaced with the same thing but with some characters in uppercase.

If the underlying system evaluates strings case-insensitively so much, why would its AV software not also use case-insensitive pattern matching?

Comment: Could you also point out the relevant portion of the video demonstrating this? One and a half hours is a bit too long for me to watch :)

Comment: Because AV software never has been perfect? Because they want less false positives?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://youtu.be/9pwMCHlNma4?t=1617

Comment: @ThomasWeller Considering string that are file names like `wdigest.dll`, legitimate software would most likely have the string *without* case-switching some characters like demonstrated so making it case-insensitive shouldn't considerably increase false positives.